# Generating a image with a List in python Pillow doesnt work

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I recently started using pillow for some project but I can't manage to generate a image with a list object. Every int in the list has a value between 0 and 255.
So this is my relevant code:

```
 img = Image.new('L',(width,height))
 img.putdata(pixel) 
 img.save('img.png')
```

The output is always a completely black picture, even when I change every element in pixel to 0.
I also tried using 'RGB' mode istead of 'L' mode, but then I get this error:

> SystemError: new style getargs format but argument is not a tuple

I don't really undestand the error, I also changed the list, so that It holds all 3 RGB values as tuples.

Any idea what the problems might be?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use like this:

```
from PIL import Image

pixel = []
for i in range(300*100):
    pixel.append((255,0,0))
for i in range(300*100):
    pixel.append((0,255,0))
for i in range(300*100):
    pixel.append((0,0,255))
img = Image.new('RGB',(300,300))
img.putdata(pixel) 
img.show()
```

Then you get:

[image]

> SystemError: new style getargs format but argument is not a tuple

means you should use rgb like the "(R,G,B)" (a [tuple](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=tuple#tuple)).

Comment: Thanks! That solved the problem!
My mistake was, that I used a 2-Dimensional List